# Cannot find the specs of Kubernetes Manifests

Tags: kubernetes

I've been through a huge amount of stuff on https://kubernetes.io/docs/ and just want to be able to find definitions of what fields I need for what K8s structures I'm trying to develop. I want to be able to create persistent volumes and understand what the options are and be able to encode that in a sensible way. Surely these are somewhere?

I get this is a terrible question, but I feel like I'm trying to code these manifests up with a mixture of random rubbish from Google and examples, which I'm pretty sure is a terrible way to develop production critical infrastructure.

Comment: Feels like you want to know about the api for kubernetes resource, you can check for instance here (for v1.15) https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/ or through `kubectl explain` for instance to check description of pv spec with `kubectl explain persistentvolume.spec`

Comment: I'd say that's an answer @gonzalesraul

Comment: Genuinely changed everything -- thanks! Put this as an answer and I'll accept it please @gonzalesraul

Comment: Just "prettified it" as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the resource spec for kubernetes by consulting the [Web API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15) (this is for v1.15).

If you do not want to leave the CLI, you can also use `kubectl explain`, for instance:

```sh
# check description of a persistent volume spec
$ kubectl explain persistentvolume.spec
```